# SELECT mostrar 2 dígitos del año

Tags: jquery

Necesito que en un desplegable que contiene años en el desplegable se muestren con 4 dígitos pero cuando selecciona debe mostrar los últimos 2.
Debería quedar algo parecido a esto cuando haya un valor seleccionado:
[image: Valor seleccionado]
Pero cuando está desplegado así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve haciendo pruebas pero me cambia el valor cuando el combo está desplegado. Mis pruebas están en este [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4h21bw37/7/)

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: No le veo sentido a lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: Se puede hacer pero es complicado... ¿Para qué necesitas esto?

Comment: Lo pide un cliente y no hay manera de hacerle entrar en razón.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre para solucionar tu problema es lo siguiente:

1. Capturar en variables globales tanto el `option` seleccionado como su contenido.
2. Una vez que de ejecute el evento `change` del `select` debemos quitarle el foco con el fin de que cada que el `select` recupere el foco cambie el texto del ultimo elemento seleccionado con su valor inicial siempre y cuando exista un último elemento seleccionado, es ahí donde se usarían las variables globales.

Te dejo el ejemplo funcional:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text = '';
  var ultimo_seleccionado;
  
  $('#yearOfYear').change(function(){
    ultimo_seleccionado = $('#yearOfYear option:selected');
    text = ultimo_seleccionado.text();

    ultimo_seleccionado.text(text.substring(2));

    $('#yearOfYear').blur();
  });

  $('#yearOfYear').focus(function(){
    if(ultimo_seleccionado != undefined){
      ultimo_seleccionado.text(text);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="yearOfYear">
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien! Gracias!